# Schedule JobIntentService in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

I'm moving the [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)s of my app to JobIntentServices, but some of my IntentServices were beeing runing with an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule the IntentService run using a PendingIntent

How can I schedule the JobIntentService run supporting Android 16+?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have `AlarmManager` use a `PendingIntent` pointing at a `BroadcastReceiver`. Have the receiver, in `onReceive()`, call `enqueueWork()` for the `JobIntentService`.